# Compute percents from SUM() in the same SELECT sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.1

In the table `my_obj` there are two integer fields:

```
(value_a integer, value_b integer);
```

I try to compute how many time `value_a = value_b`, and I want to express this ratio in percents.
This is the code I have tried:

```
select sum(case when o.value_a = o.value_b then 1 else 0 end) as nb_ok,
       sum(case when o.value_a != o.value_b then 1 else 0 end) as nb_not_ok,
       compute_percent(nb_ok,nb_not_ok)
from  my_obj as o
group by o.property_name;
```

`compute_percent` is a stored_procedure that simply does `(a * 100) / (a + b)`

But PostgreSQL complains that the column `nb_ok` doesn't exist.
How would you do that properly ?

I use PostgreSQL 9.1 with Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: `But postgresql complains that the column nook doesn't exist.` ? Please fix your question, there is no `nook` anywhere. When talking about an error message, put it in your question **as is**. Copy / Paste.

Comment: Consider the last paragraph of my answer and follow the link to the manual to understand why `nbok` appears in lower case.

Comment: Upper-casing of SQL keywords is totally optional and a matter of taste. But lower casing of identifiers is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more to this question than it may seem.

#### Simple version

This is **much** faster and simpler:

```
SELECT property_name
      ,(count(value_a = value_b OR NULL) * 100) / count(*) AS pct
FROM   my_obj
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Result:

```
property_name | pct
--------------+----
 prop_1       | 17
 prop_2       | 43
```

How?

- You don't need a function for this at all.
- Instead of counting `value_b` (which you don't need to begin with) and calculating the total, use `count(*)` for the total. Faster, simpler.
- This assumes you don't have **`NULL`** values. I.e. both columns are defined `NOT NULL`. The information is missing in your question.
  If not, your original query is **probably not doing what you think it does**. If any of the values is NULL, your version does not count that row at all. You could even provoke a *division-by-zero* exception this way.
  This version works with NULL, too. `count(*)` produces the count of all rows, regardless of values.
- Here's how the count works:

  ```
   TRUE  OR NULL = TRUE
   FALSE OR NULL = NULL
  ```

  `count()` ignores NULL values. Voilá.
- [Operator precedence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE) governs that `=` binds before `OR`. You could add parentheses to make it clearer:

  ```
  count ((value_a = value_b) OR FALSE)
  ```
- You can do the same with

  ```
  count NULLIF(<expression>, FALSE)
  ```
- The result type of `count()` is `bigint` by default.
  A division `bigint / bigint`, **truncates fractional digits**.

#### Include fractional digits

Use **`100.0`** (with fractional digit) to force the calculation to be `numeric` and thereby preserve fractional digits.
You may want to use [`round()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) with this:

```
SELECT property_name
      ,round((count(value_a = value_b OR NULL) * 100.0) / count(*), 2) AS pct
FROM   my_obj
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Result:

```
property_name | pct
--------------+-------
 prop_1       | 17.23
 prop_2       | 43.09
```

As an aside:
I use `value_a` instead of `valueA`. Don't use unquoted mixed-case identifiers in PostgreSQL. I have seen too many desperate question coming from this folly. If you wonder what I am talking about, read the chapter [Identifiers and Key Words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) in the manual.

Comment: Does this `COUNT` run faster than the similar SUM((value_a=value_b)::integer) or the analogous `SUM(CASE...)`?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus: The difference is generally marginal, as each of the three forms is very cheap compared to reading data from disk. In my last test `OR` came before `CASE` and `::int`. But `OR`, `CASE` an `NULLIF` were "to close to call", really. You can test this easily. Here is a [recent similar test on dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27572/3684) (but without an `OR` version).

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way to do is to just use a with clause

```
WITH data 
     AS (SELECT Sum(CASE WHEN o.valuea = o.valueb THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS nbOk, 
                Sum(CASE WHEN o.valuea != o.valueb THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS nbNotOk, 
         FROM   my_obj AS o 
         GROUP  BY o.property_name) 
SELECT nbok, 
       nbnotok, 
       Compute_percent(nbok, nbnotok) 
FROM   data
```

Comment: Supposing a covering index on one/both columns, will the optimizer be able to use them for this query (and in what capacity), or will it be a strict table scan?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse it works just like an in-line query. It will use whatever it can to build the `data` but after that everything is done in memory.

Comment: @ConradFrix I made a mistake in my question, i'm going to edit, the `group by` is `group by o.property_name`. It doesn't make sense otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to try this version:

```
WITH all(count) as (SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM my_obj),
     matching(count) as (SELECT COUNT(*)
                         FROM my_obj
                         WHERE valueA = valueB)
SELECT nbOk, nbNotOk, Compute_percent(nbOk, nbNotOk)
FROM (SELECT matching.count as nbOk, all.count - matching.count as nbNotOk
      FROM all
      CROSS JOIN matching) data
```