# Group by multiple criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Given the table like

```
| userid | active | anonymous |
|   1    |   t    |    f      |
|   2    |   f    |    f      |
|   3    |   f    |    t      |
```

I need to get:

- number of users
- number of users with 'active' = true
- number of users with 'active' = false
- number of users with 'anonymous' = true
- number of users with 'anonymous' = false

with single query.

As for now, I only came out with the solution using **union**:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*) FROM mytable where active
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*) FROM mytable where anonymous
```

So I can take first number and find non-active and non-anonymous users with simple deduction .

Is there any way to get rid of union and calculate number of records matching these simple conditions with some *magic and efficient* query in **PostgreSQL 9**?

Comment: You forgot to mention `NOT NULL` constraints, primary key, data types and other relevant information about your table. Also PostgreSQL 9.? - [First *and* second part of the version number are relevant for major version.](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your columns are `boolean NOT NULL`, this should be a bit faster:

```
SELECT total_ct
      ,active_ct
      ,(total_ct - active_ct) AS not_active_ct
      ,anon_ct
      ,(total_ct - anon_ct) AS not_anon_ct
FROM  (
   SELECT count(*) AS total_ct
         ,count(active OR NULL) AS active_ct
         ,count(anonymous OR NULL) AS anon_ct
   FROM  tbl
   ) sub;
```

Find a detailed explanation for the techniques used in this closely related answer:
[Compute percents from SUM() in the same SELECT sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644713/compute-percents-from-sum-in-the-same-select-sql-query/15650897#15650897)

Indexes are hardly going to be of any use, since the whole table has to be read anyway. A covering index might be of help if your rows are bigger than in the example. Depends on the specifics of your actual table.

-> [**SQLfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9e6be/1) comparing to [@bluefeet's version with `CASE` statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16159042/939860) for each value.

SQL server folks are not used to the proper `boolean` type of Postgres and tend to go the long way round.

Comment: I knew you would come in with a better postgreSQL answer. I guess I need to learn this DB a bit more.

Comment: @bluefeet: I do what I can. ;) There is just too much too learn with the major RDBMS versions alone.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` to get the result in separate columns:

```
select 
  count(*) TotalUsers,
  sum(case when active = 't' then 1 else 0 end) TotalActiveTrue,
  sum(case when active = 'f' then 1 else 0 end) TotalActiveFalse,
  sum(case when anonymous = 't' then 1 else 0 end) TotalAnonTrue,
  sum(case when anonymous = 'f' then 1 else 0 end) TotalAnonFalse
from mytable;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/3907b/1)

Comment: I looked at the execution plan and realized, that this query does not use any index which I have on the table, e.g 'create index table_anon on mytable((anonymous=true))'. So it has 'seq scan' and doesn't use any filter.