# Improve performance of custom aggregate function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, count, boolean, case, aggregate-functions

I have custom aggregate sum function which accepts boolean data type:

```
create or replace function badd (bigint, boolean)
  returns bigint as
$body$
select $1 + case when $2 then 1 else 0 end;
$body$ language sql;

create aggregate sum(boolean) (
  sfunc=badd,
  stype=int8,
  initcond='0'
);
```

This aggregate should calculate number of rows with `TRUE`. For example the following should return 2 (and it does):

```
with t (x) as 
   (values 
      (true::boolean), 
      (false::boolean), 
      (true::boolean),
      (null::boolean)      
      )
select sum(x) from t;
```

However, it's performance is quite bad, it is 5.5 times slower then using casting to integer:

```
with t as (select (gs > 0.5) as test_vector from generate_series(1,1000000,1) gs)
select sum(test_vector) from t; -- 52012ms

with t as (select (gs > 0.5) as test_vector from generate_series(1,1000000,1) gs)
select sum(test_vector::int) from t; -- 9484ms
```

Is the only way how to improve this aggregate to write some new C function - e.g. some alternative of `int2_sum` function in `src/backend/utils/adt/numeric.c`?

Comment: That's not an int2-sum. It's a bool-sum, so more like bit-1. And it's wrong, too. It should be: `$1 + $2::int`, or `$1 + case $2 when true then 1 else 0 end`, or something to that order.

Comment: I still don't see the reason for a custom aggregate, both `select sum(x::int) from t;` and `select sum(1) from t where x;` are correct and much faster

Comment: @Denis I updated my question, my aggregate works correctly and does what I want to, but it is slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test case is misleading, you only count `TRUE`. You should have both TRUE *and* FALSE - or even NULL, if applicable.

[Like @foibs already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20316098/939860), one wouldn't use a custom aggregate function for this. The built-in C-functions are *much* faster and do the job. Use instead (also demonstrating a simpler and more sensible test):

```
SELECT count(NULLIF(g%2 = 1, FALSE)) AS ct
FROM  generate_series(1,100000,1) g;
```

How does this work?
[Compute percents from SUM() in the same SELECT sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644713/compute-percents-from-sum-in-the-same-select-sql-query/15650897#15650897)

Several fast & simple ways (plus a benchmark) under this related answer on dba.SE:
[For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/for-absolute-performance-is-sum-faster-or-count/27572)

Or faster yet, test for `TRUE` in the `WHERE` clause, *where possible*:

```
SELECT count(*) AS ct
FROM   generate_series(1,100000,1) g;
WHERE  g%2 = 1             -- excludes FALSE and NULL !
```

---

**If** you'd have to write a custom aggregate for some reason, this form would be superior:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_sum_int8 (int8, boolean)
  RETURNS bigint as
'SELECT CASE WHEN $2 THEN $1 + 1 ELSE $1 END' LANGUAGE sql;
```

The addition is only executed when necessary. Your original would add `0` for the `FALSE` case.

Better yet, use a **plpgsql** function. It saves a bit of overhead per call, since it works like a prepared statement (the query is not re-planned). Makes a difference for a tiny aggregate function that is called *many* times:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_sum_plpgsql (int8, boolean)
  RETURNS bigint AS
$func$
BEGIN
RETURN CASE WHEN $2 THEN $1 + 1 ELSE $1 END;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE AGGREGATE test_sum_plpgsql(boolean) (
  sfunc = test_sum_plpgsql
 ,stype = int8
 ,initcond = '0'
);
```

Faster than what you had, but much slower than the presented alternative with a standard `count()`. And slower than any other C-function, too.

[**->SQLfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6f33c/4)

Comment: Ooh, you are right, my test case should be: `with t as (select (random() > 0.5) as test_vector from generate_series(1,1000000,1) gs)
select sum(test_vector) from t;` I'll try to write my own C function.

Answer (score 3):

I created custom C function and aggregate for boolean:

C function:

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include <fmgr.h>

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

int
bool_sum(int arg, bool tmp)
{
  if (tmp)
    {
    arg++;
    } 
    return arg;
}
```

Transition and aggregate functions:

```
-- transition function
create or replace function bool_sum(bigint, boolean)
  returns bigint
   AS '/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib/bool_agg', 'bool_sum'
  language C strict
  cost 1;
alter function bool_sum(bigint, boolean) owner to postgres;

-- aggregate
create aggregate sum(boolean) (
  sfunc=bool_sum,
  stype=int8,
  initcond='0'
);
alter aggregate sum(boolean) owner to postgres;
```

Performance test:

```
-- Performance test - 10m rows

create table tmp_test as (select (case when random() <.3 then null when random() < .6 then true else false end) as test_vector from generate_series(1,10000000,1) gs);

-- Casting to integer
select sum(test_vector::int) from tmp_test;

-- Boolean sum
select sum(test_vector) from tmp_test;
```

Now `sum(boolean)` is as fast as `sum(boolean::int)`.

**Update:**

It turns out that I can call existing C transition functions directly, even with boolean data type. It gets somehow magically converted to 0/1 on the way. So my current solution for boolean sum and average is:

```
create or replace function bool_sum(bigint, boolean)
  returns bigint as
'int2_sum'
  language internal immutable
  cost 1;


create aggregate sum(boolean) (
  sfunc=bool_sum,
  stype=int8
);

-- Average for boolean values (percentage of rows with TRUE)
create or replace function bool_avg_accum(bigint[], boolean)
  returns bigint[] as
'int2_avg_accum'
  language internal immutable strict
  cost 1;

create aggregate avg(boolean) (
  sfunc=bool_avg_accum,
  stype=int8[],
  finalfunc=int8_avg,
  initcond='{0,0}'
);
```

Comment: +1 For providing your interesting solution. Even if it wouldn't be necessary for the presented case, it may be useful for related problems.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I've updated my answer - there is no need for custom C function and still it will be as fast as built in aggregates.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the real issue here. First of all, using `sum` as your custom aggregate name is wrong. When you call `sum` with your `test_vector` cast to int, the embedded postgres sum is used and not yours, that's why it is so much faster. A C function will always be faster, but I'm not sure you need one in this case.

You could easily drop the `badd` function and your custom `sum` use the embedded `sum` with a where clause

```
with t as (select 1 as test_vector from generate_series(1,1000000,1) gs where gs > 0.5)
select sum(test_vector) from t;
```

**EDIT:**

To sum it up, the best way to optimize your custom aggregate is to remove it if it is not needed. The second best way would be to write a C function.