# Counting totals and partials

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, aggregate-functions

I have a table `answers` in a PostgreSQL engine powered database, with a number associated to a question. I need to count how many numbers are there and how many of them are below 6 grouped by question.

What I want is something like:

```
SELECT question, count(*) AS Qanswers, count_below_6(*) AS Qanswers_below_6
FROM answers
GROUP BY question;

      question         | Qanswers | Qanswers_below_6
-----------------------+----------+------------------
How do you feel?       |  1234    |      53
Was clear the webinar? |  8444    |      20
How much that hurt?    |  3666    |     142
```

Currently I'm doing

```
SELECT question, count(*) AS Qanswers
FROM answers
GROUP BY question;
```

And then

```
SELECT question, count(*) AS Qanswers
FROM answers
WHERE value < 6
GROUP BY question;
```

After that I merge the two results manually.
Can I make a single sentence that gives me the result as I need?

Comment: `postgresql engine powered database`? Does this mean you have a database that is not PostgreSQL, but is using its engine?  I'd be curious to see said database.  Is it on GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT question
      ,count(*) AS answers
      ,count(value < 6 OR NULL) AS under_6
FROM   answers
GROUP  BY question;
```

The trick is that `count(expression)` only counts non-null values (while `count(*)` counts *all* rows). Here is a detailed explanation why we get NULL in the right places:
[Compute percents from SUM() in the same SELECT sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644713/compute-percents-from-sum-in-the-same-select-sql-query/15650897#15650897)

There is a number of equivalent techniques to achieve that. Detailed comparison with a benchmark:
[For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/for-absolute-performance-is-sum-faster-or-count/27572#27572)

Comment: It might be interesting to include using range-tables as part of that performance analysis - eg, using `SELECT question, COUNT(*) AS answers, COUNT(low) AS under_6 FROM Answers LEFT JOIN (VALUES (6)) Lim(low) ON Answers.value < Lim.low GROUP BY question`.  Granted, it's easier to do more complicated conditions with `CASE` and related...