# How can I join these tables in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query like this:

```
select *, (CAST (ie_usage_count as float)/total_count)*100 as percent_ie from(

SELECT DISTINCT CAST (account_id AS bigint),
    count(case when 
            user_agent LIKE '%MSIE 7%'
            AND user_agent NOT LIKE '%Trident%' 
            then 1 end) as ie_usage_count,
    count(*) as total_usage
FROM acc_logs
WHERE account_id NOT LIKE 'Account ID '
group by account_id
ORDER BY account_id )
where not ie_usage_count = 0
```

That gives me a table with account_ids, and the ie_usage_count, total_usage, and percent_ie associated with each account ID

```
account_id | ie_usage_count | total_usage | percent_ie
```

I have another query

```
select name, account_id
from accounts
```

That gives me the name of the person associated with each account.

```
name | account_id |
```

I'd like to have a single query that includes name, account_id, ie_usage_count, total_usage, and percent_ie.

```
name | account_id | ie_usage_count | total_usage | percent_ie
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first query is more easily written as:

```
select CAST(account_id AS bigint),
       SUM(case when  user_agent LIKE '%MSIE 7%' AND user_agent NOT LIKE '%Trident%' 
                then 1 else 0
            end) as ie_usage_count,
       count(*) as total_usage,
       AVG(case when  user_agent LIKE '%MSIE 7%' AND user_agent NOT LIKE '%Trident%' 
                then 100.0 else 0
            end) as percent_ie
from acc_logs
where account_id NOT LIKE 'Account ID '
group by account_id
having SUM(case when  user_agent LIKE '%MSIE 7%' AND user_agent NOT LIKE '%Trident%' 
                then 1 else 0
            end) <> 0;
```

You can get the name just by joining it in:

```
select CAST(al.account_id AS bigint), a.name,
       SUM(case when user_agent LIKE '%MSIE 7%' AND user_agent NOT LIKE '%Trident%' 
                then 1 else 0
            end) as ie_usage_count,
       count(*) as total_usage,
       AVG(case when  user_agent LIKE '%MSIE 7%' AND user_agent NOT LIKE '%Trident%' 
                then 100.0 else 0
            end) as percent_ie
from acc_logs al join
     accounts a
     on al.account_id = a.account_id
where al.account_id NOT LIKE 'Account ID '
group by al.account_id, a.name
having SUM(case when  user_agent LIKE '%MSIE 7%' AND user_agent NOT LIKE '%Trident%' 
                then 1 else 0
            end) <> 0;
```

Comment: I get ERROR: column al.name does not exist

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED but perhaps something simple like a join, add on account_ID and then addition of a group by... but this makes several assumptions .. like acc_Logs has all accounts, or you only want percent_IE when there is a log entry... if no acc_Log or no account then no record...

```
select *, (CAST (ie_usage_count as float)/total_count)*100 as percent_ie from(

SELECT DISTINCT CAST (B.account_id AS bigint),
    count(case when 
            user_agent LIKE '%MSIE 7%'
            AND user_agent NOT LIKE '%Trident%' 
            then 1 end) as ie_usage_count,
    count(*) as total_usage,
    A.name
FROM acc_logs B
INNER JOIN Accounts A
 on A.Account_ID = B.account_ID
WHERE B.account_id NOT LIKE 'Account ID '
group by B.account_id, A.Name
ORDER BY B.account_id )
where not ie_usage_count = 0
```

added alias to tables.

Comment: I get ERROR: column reference "account_id" is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

Just join to it:

```
SELECT a.name, l.*, (l.ie_usage_count * 100)::float / l.total_count AS percent_ie
FROM  (
   SELECT account_id::bigint       -- Why cast to bigint?
        , count(user_agent LIKE '%MSIE 7%'
            AND user_agent NOT LIKE '%Trident%' 
            OR NULL) AS ie_usage_count
        , count(*) AS total_usage
   FROM   acc_logs
   WHERE  account_id NOT LIKE 'Account ID '  -- trailing blank? typo?
   GROUP  BY account_id
   ORDER  BY account_id
   ) l
JOIN  accounts a USING (account_id)
WHERE ie_usage_count <> 0;
```

- Your original query was invalid, because the subquery had no alias.
  Otherwise, the subquery is just fine, don't flatten it. Short syntax, percentage calculation and join to `accounts` only for qualifying rows, division by 0 avoided elegantly.
- Why do you cast `account_id` to `bigint`? There's something off here. Are you storing numbers as text? I would need to see your table definitions ...
- Reformulated the calculation. It's cheaper and more precise to multiply the `integer` by 100 *before* you cast to `float`.
  You may want to cast to `numeric` instead and wrap that into [`round(expression, 2)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) to get pretty output.
- Using a shorter (equivalent) expression for the conditional count. [Details here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644713/compute-percents-from-sum-in-the-same-select-sql-query/15650897#15650897)
- Simplified your `WHERE` condition.