# Transpose PostgreSQL table or aggregation function doing nothing

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I've got a PostgreSQL table which I have to transpose.
The original data looks like:

```
user_id role_id assigned
P0001   SA      t
P0001   Guest   t
P0002   SA      f
P0002   Guest   t
```

After transposing, it should look like as follows:

```
user_id SA  Guest
P0001   t   t
P0002   f   t
```

The following is what I used to generate the transposed table:

```
SELECT user_id, 
CAST(CAST(CASE role_id WHEN 'SA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS int) AS boolean) AS "SA",
CAST(CAST((CASE role_id WHEN 'Guest' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS int) AS boolean) AS "Guest" 
FROM user_to_roles GROUP BY user_id
```

But it looks ugly. Is there a way to write an custom aggregation function doing nothing but returning the original value. So the above statement can be re-written as:

```
SELECT user_id, 
Do_Nothing(CASE role_id WHEN 'SA' THEN true ELSE false END) AS "SA",
Do_Nothing(CASE role_id WHEN 'Guest' THEN true ELSE false END) AS "Guest" 
FROM user_to_roles GROUP BY user_id
```

#### Edit:

Actually, I need a dynamic generated columns and implemented it using the cursor by the help of [this article](http://okbob.blogspot.hk/2008/08/using-cursors-for-generating-cross.html). And I looked into the documentation and write a custom aggregation like this:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE do_nothing(anyelement) (
  SFUNC=donothing,
  STYPE=anyelement,
  INITCOND=''
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION donothing(anyelement var)
  RETURNS anyelement AS
$BODY$
    RETURN var;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE
  COST 100;
```

Since I want to make it generic, `anyelment` was used here.
But the above code doesn't work at all.

Comment: "*Is there a way to write an custom aggregation*" - yes that should be possible: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createaggregate.html Search the Postgres Wiki. I think there are some examples there. You also might want to look into the `crosstab` function: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html

Comment: This is a table pivot, or crosstab, and it's a bit of an FAQ. Partly because it's annoyingly ugly and hard to do in a general way in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Cross-tabulation / Pivoting is a completely different concept than aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `crosstab()`

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
       'SELECT user_id, role_id, assigned
        FROM   tbl
        ORDER  BY 1,2'

      ,$$VALUES ('SA'::text), ('Guest')$$)
AS ct (user_id text, "SA" bool, "Guest" bool);
```

That's as **fast** as it gets with current versions of Postgres. (Faster than alternatives below.)

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

But neither of these solutions is completely "dynamic", which is *not completely possible*:

- [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334)

For a completely dynamic solution, you would have to output arrays or some other container type to return a variable number of columns. Recent related question with answers:

- [Looping in select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401494/looping-in-select-query/25408029)

### Poor man's crosstab with aggregated `CASE` expressions

For just a few columns: simple `CASE` statements combined with an aggregate function.

`min()` or `max()` work for most basic types ... [per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html):

> any array, numeric, string, or date/time type

But not for `boolean`. Use `bool_or()` like [@Richard suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25420847/939860).
`FALSE OR NULL` would yield `NULL`, but all mentioned aggregate functions (incl. `bool_or()`) *ignore* `NULL`, so it works with `NULL` as well.

```
SELECT user_id
      ,bool_or(CASE WHEN role_id = 'SA'    THEN assigned ELSE NULL END) AS "SA"
      ,bool_or(CASE WHEN role_id = 'Guest' THEN assigned ELSE NULL END) AS "Guest"
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

You have to adapt to the data type expected.

#### Custom aggregate for *any* type

There is no standard aggregate function that works for *any* data type in the way you need it. You can create one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_echo1(anyelement,anyelement)
  RETURNS anyelement AS 'SELECT $1' LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE AGGREGATE first_notnull(anyelement) (
   SFUNC = f_echo1
 , STYPE = anyelement
);
```

This is a simple, working version of what you outlined in your edit:
Starting with `NULL` (no `INITCOND`), using a `STRICT` transition function, it takes the first not-null value and the transition function just keeps that one. So we get the first not-null value back the aggregate function encounters.

This works for *any* input type:

```
SELECT user_id
      ,first_notnull(CASE WHEN role_id = 'SA'    THEN assigned ELSE NULL END) AS "SA"
      ,first_notnull(CASE WHEN role_id = 'Guest' THEN assigned ELSE NULL END) AS "Guest"
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

#### Copy `bool_or()` as `max()`

Custom aggregate functions in sql or plpgsql are considerably slower than the built-in ones, which are written in C and optimized. You could write one in C yourself. Wouldn't be that hard. Or you can copy the definition of `bool_or` under the name of `max` in `pg_proc` and  reference it in another copy in `pg_aggregate` to make `max()` work for `boolean` as well. Messing with catalog tables is not recommended for the casual user, though. If you break something your system might go belly-up ...

Comment: Thanks for so elegant solution and useful link!

Comment: It seems that MAX doesn't work with boolean. It throws an exception stating that function max(boolean) does not exist. It works fine with string and null. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3496167 I added some.

Comment: I tried the custom aggregation function, now it works a like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case you can get away with using a built-in aggregate [bool_or](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-aggregate.html). Something like:

```
SELECT user_id, 
bool_or(CASE role_id WHEN 'SA'    THEN assigned ELSE false END) AS "SA",
bool_or(CASE role_id WHEN 'Guest' THEN assigned ELSE false END) AS "Guest" 
FROM user_to_roles GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Since I want to do it in generic way, is there a similar aggregation function applied to string and int?

Comment: For int, you could use `sum` and an alternate value of 0. For text `string_agg` and the empty string.

Comment: @user3496167: Use `ELSE NULL`, then either of the aggregate functions (min, max, sum) works with *any* type. I added a code example to my answer.

Comment: @user3496167: I was promising too much. `min()` and `max()` work for *most* basic types, but not for `boolean`. I added more to my answer.